# Instantiate bean annotated ContextConfiguration annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I have fololowing java class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/pathToXml" })
public class AbstractServiceTest  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    protected MyBean myBean;

    public Integer doSomething(){
       return myBean.returnVeryImportantInteger();
    }
        ...
}
```

If I write `new AbstractServiceTest ()`

sessionFactory is null.(sessionFacory info wrote in pathToXml)

How can I say spring that it see configuration from `"classpath:/pathToXml"` ?

```
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/anotherPathToXml" })
    public class MyClass
        public void myMethod(){
           // I want to use here method doSomething from AbstractServiceTest class
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let spring instantiate that `AbstractServiceTest` for you and autowire it where you need it.
Spring will then check for context configuration and do the autowiring stuff.

Since I can see this is a test class, are you running it with a `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`)?

Comment: I want to use methods from this class in another class(Class B).

Comment: When you instantiate yourself a class with `new` this is the normal Java mechanism which takes place, Spring is not called and cannot know so it's normal that your member is `null`. You need to use `@Autowired` in your other class to have the correct instance configured by Spring